# Return table row as a HTML code via ajax and add in table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am coding an application which fetches the data from data base on the basis of `id` given and return row in table, it is a bar code billing module, it `.append` the row as the barcode string given, but the problem which I am facing, when I am returning table `row as a HTML` code `<tr>..</tr>`, via `ajax` I cannot see the new table row printed(added) on my table.

Here is my view:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">


              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>S No.</th>
                  <th>Particular</th>
                  <th>QTY</th>
                  <th>Cost</th>
                <th>Discount</th>
                <th>Discard</th>


                </tr>
              </thead>

               <tbody class="todo_list">
               <?php echo $list;?>
             <input type="hidden" name="bill_ref" value="<?php echo $bill_ref ?>"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo $date ?>"/>

               </tbody>
               <?php echo $total_bill; ?> 

                <div id="bill_tbl">
                      <--!MY NEW ROW SUPPOSED TO BE ADDED HERE!-->
            </div>
            </table>
```

My ajax JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


               $("#c_id").change(function(){
                     var send_data=$("#c_id").val();
                     $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"billing_table",
                        dataType: "html",

                        data:"i_id_post="+send_data,
                        success:function(data){
                              $("#bill_tbl")..after(data);

                        }

                     });
               });
           });
</script>
```

and my controller (for testing purpose i am operating my DB part in controller i am sorry for this):

```
public function billing_table()
    {
    $b_barcodestring=$this->input->post('b_barcodestring');
    $i_id=$this->input->post('i_id_post');
    if($i_id==''&& $b_barcodestring!='')
    {

    echo $b_barcodestring;

    }
    else if($b_barcodestring=='' && $i_id!='' )
    {


    //i want to print sumple this dummy row in my table
    echo '<tr ><input type="hidden" name="counter[]" value="ssss"></tr><tr ><td>+counter+</td>  <input type="hidden" name="particular[]" value="Greting Card" ><td>'.$i_id.'</td>  <td>  <input type="number" name="qty[]" value="+qty_cal+"></td> <td> <input type="hidden" name="cost[]" value="150" >150</td> <td><input type="hidden" name="discount[]" value="N/A">N/A</input></td> <td ><button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>Delete</button></td></tr>';
    }

    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    }
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mxcWm/82).

Comment: instead of $("#bill_tbl")..after(data) try $("#bill_tbl").after(data)

Comment: @VinodLouis : ya i tried extra " . " was my typing mistake , its still not working

Comment: I don't think you can add a row to a table outside tbody or thead, i mean I think it won't be w3c compliant, but not sure if it's the origin of the issue. You should really consider review your output layout imho.

Comment: First check the received `data` in `success` method. simply alert that. if there was an error, make sure that you are not using CodeIgniter CSRF prevention feature. If so, just do a little search on SO to find the solution.

Comment: can it be done with JSON?? how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following line in the `JS` function

```
success:function(data){
      //$("#bill_tbl")..after(data);
      $(".table").append(data);
}
```

Remove the div#bill_tbl from the table

Comment: have you checked that you are getting the correct response from `ajax`? Checked your console for the response you are getting?

Comment: what you have done in your `jsfiddle`, change to `$(".todo_list").append(data);`

Comment: Happie to help :D @user2652367

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$("#c_id").change(function(){

    var send_data=$("#c_id").val();
    var b_barcodestring = $("#b_id").val(); //your barcodestring , I just supplement it cannot find where you getting it

    $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"billing_table",
    dataType: "html",
    data:{
      i_id_post : send_data, //This is the correct format for your data to send
      b_barcodestring : b_barcodestring
    },
    success:function(data){

      $("#bill_tbl").append(data);

    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

you can change the div to table and try this it will work

```
 function addrow(){
     $("#mytable").after("<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>");
 }
```

working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/LvekG/)

In your case change this div(bill_tbl) to table

Comment: i am not coding to add row on click, i want to get row that returned from ajx

Comment: just use the returned HTML string inside the function as a parameter if you data in success is a valid HTML string it will append just make sure its an table

Comment: what is your JSON string here ?

Comment: i am just asking...can it be done...if yes then please, prompt me with the hint

Comment: if you have any valid string like "<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>" you can pass it inside the function